# Approximating surface area of a scalene ellipsoid

Tags: integration, conic-sections, 3d, area

I'm doing a high school paper on surface area of ellipsoids. I can find the SA of a ellipsoid of revolution, but do not know how to find the SA for a scalene ellipsoid. I would like to avoid elliptic integrals, and instead somehow approximate the SA. What techniques are available to approximate multivariable functions?

[image: These are the equations i am working with]

Also, would it be easier to approximate the second equation $z(x,y)$ and then evaluate the double integral?

The goal is to approximate into a form such that i can evaluate the double integral in simple terms, without elliptic integrals.

Answer (score 1):

There is an *approximation* proposed by Knud Thomsen in year $2004$ (have a look [here](http://www.numericana.com/answer/ellipsoid.htm#spheroid))
$$S\approx2\pi \Big((ab)^p+(bc)^p+(ac)^p \Big)^{\frac 1 p}\quad \text{where}\quad p=\frac{\log (3)}{\log (2)}$$

In the linked page, you will find discussions about the optimal value of $p$ as well as other formulae.

Using [this](https://fin-calc.org.ua/en/calculator/geometry/surface/ellipsoid/) online calculator for $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=4$  we get $S=111.604$ while the above formula gives $111.504$.

There is another approximation by the same author (Knud Thomsen)
$$S\approx 4\pi \Big(\frac{(ab)^p+(bc)^p+(ac)^p}3 \Big)^{\frac 1 p}\quad \text{where}\quad p\sim 1.6075$$

Comment: Would you happen to know how this is derived?

Comment: @J.V.. I have not been able to find the paper. Sorry for that.